# Can an election be canceled if the elected candidate has saturated medias

Tags: european-union, elections

I was reading a short story of Philip K. Dick, "What the dead men say". It is (spoil) about the voice of a dead person litteraly overtaking every available media (television, radio, telephone, newspapers...) to force the election of a candidate by saying things like "Vote for him, he's the best", 24/7. It can't be stopped because the interference source is astronomicaly too far. The conclusion was that this candidate will be elected, because of the brainwashing currently happening.

And I thought... this kind of thing can technically happen : a candidate can submerge every media with videos or audios to his/her glory. Every television channel, every website, every newspaper says the same thing : "Vote for him !" but nothing could be linked to him/her, as the source can't be found. It is more than propaganda ; it's really brainwashing.
Finally, this candidate win the election ; but after a few months it is found he/she was at the origin of the "hack".

If something like this happen, can the election be canceled ? I'm mostly interested by europe, but I'm curious of other countries.

Answer (score 1):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

> Can an election be canceled if the elected candidate has saturated
> medias?

No. Indeed, many completely legal election campaigns are grossly one-sided with the opponents of one candidate doing almost no campaigning and a leading candidate saturating the media.

Also, generally speaking, even very serious campaign finance law violations are not grounds for undoing an election result.